# Programmatically Create a Custom Table View as a Popup

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Like the title says, I'm working on an Xcode project using Swift 3.0. I'd like to have, my current view, on a button click, display a smaller view as a pop up. 
 This pop up will be a Table View that will display one label + one text box for as many cells are in a certain array. The size will be limited to a piece of the screen and the table view will naturally be scrollable.

I understand how to programmatically create a view and I got the "hidden = true" concept. What I'm really struggling with is getting the Table View in it. Theoretically I could design the view in my storyboard, but would there be a way to reference it by name and super impose it over the current view?

Thanks for the help!

Edit:

Thanks to some help I got as far as this code:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var CreatePost: UIButton!
@IBAction func CreatePost(_ sender: Any) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let popVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CreateAccountPop") // your viewcontroller's id
    popVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 500, height: 600)
    popVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    let popover =  popVC.popoverPresentationController
    popover?.delegate = self as? UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate
    //sourceRect and sourceView is required in case of iPad
    popover?.sourceRect = (sender as AnyObject).frame //give anchor frame
    popover?.sourceView = sender as! UIView //give anchor view
    self.present(popVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The code displays the view controller but it takes up the entire screen. I can't seem to figure out how to limit its size

Comment: Did you try showing up tableview in a new view controller instead? A view controller can also be shown as popup

Comment: Do you mean something like that? https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/views/popovers/

Comment: yes, something like that. In iPhone, it comes as popup

Comment: @lufritz That looks like what I'm looking for! I'll try to implement it and hopefully it's exactly what I wanted

Comment: I think I'd still like to do it using a view for stlye purposes. @RikeshSubedi, How can I call the view controller to appear over the current view?(also shrinking it)

Comment: I am adding an answer, see if you can try it

Comment: Ah, just understood that I should use the view controller as a popover

Comment: Yeah. You can also make the background view transparent to give the overlay effect, or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design your ViewController (preferably in storyboard), make the view non opaque. Add tableview with size of your choice.

You can present the popover like this

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let popVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopVC") // your viewcontroller's id
popVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
let popover =  popVC.popoverPresentationController
popover?.delegate = self
//sourceRect and sourceView is required in case of iPad
popover?.sourceRect = sender.frame //give anchor frame
popover?.sourceView = sender //give anchor view
self.present(popVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And do not forget to conform your presenting viewcontroller to UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate

Comment: It worked but the view controller takes up the whole screen when it "pops up". How do I control the size of the controller

Comment: You cannot change the size of the controller, change the size of tableview instead.